# Specific count in SQL changing all other counts to 0 if that specific count returns 0

Tags: sql

I am running into an issue and it is making me a bit crazy. I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT f.f_id) AS `The Good`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.f_id) AS `The Bad`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT x) AS `The Ugly"`
FROM faculty f, student s, (
  SELECT f_id AS x
  FROM faculty
  MINUS (
    SELECT f.f_id
    FROM faculty f, course_section cs
    WHERE f.f_id = cs.f_id

    UNION

    SELECT f_id
    FROM student
  )
);
```

I am trying to get a count of `f_id`'s from faculty table, `f_id`'s from `student` table, and then a count of `f_id`'s from `faculty` table `MINUS` `f_id`'s from the student table and `course_section` table.

All is well if my last `COUNT` returns a number that is not `0`. However, if it returns a `0` it also changes my first two counts to a `0`. The first two `COUNT`s should be `6` and `4` respectively.

I have been trying to figure out how to fix this for a couple of hours but am having no luck.

Obviously there must be something that I am missing. What is wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using ANSI-ANCIENT notation for the joins `TableA, TableB, TableC`.

But you don't have a WHERE clause.  That's joining all the tables with every possible combination of rows (A full cartessian product).  That's a bad idea.

Also, your results don't actually require any of the tables to be joined together.  I'd recommend just using sub-queries in the SELECT clause...

```
SELECT
  (select count(distinct f_id) from faculty) "The Good",
  (select count(distinct f_id) from student) "The Bad",
  (
    select
      count(distinct f_id)
    from
    (
     select f_id from faculty
     MINUS
     select f.f_id from faculty f INNER JOIN course_section cs ON f.f_id = cs.f_id
     MINUS
     select f_id from student
    )
  ) "The Ugly"
;
-- Add FROM DUAL is this is Oracle.
```